# How can I connect and view the Display Manager using X2Go?

Tags: x2go

I'm trying to log in and view the Display Manager login screen. I'm using SDDM as Display Manager, but I can use any kind of Display Manager, like gdm, to get this working.

, but I'm only getting a black screen.

If I, however, first log in to my Xorg Server with Window Manager (XMonad), then I can connect using "Connection to local desktop".

The reason I want to do this, is because I want to troubleshoot how I can send a login command to a Display Manager, so I need to see the Display Manager, I assume.

I'm on Xorg-1.20.14 on NixOS 22.11